# How do i point my all subdomain to my vps at once

Tags: nginx, server, vps, cname, nameservers

When i used vercel, i figured that i can point `*.example.com` to my same server at `example.com` . I want to achieve that with my vps in hostinger , using apache2/ngnix. Please give me ideas on how to achieve this.

I dont want redirecting. It should show a.example.com but should be pointed to example.com

And if i want to automate the config creation of ngnix and ssl creation with my own express server. How to do that.

Please give me a brief idea.

I tried adding config file and restarting server, but wont that affect other website if i am building a hosting site with it.